# 3 text boxes that must total to 100

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So i've got 3 textfields (A, B, C) where the user can only enter numbers as the keyboard is a number pad.

I've got a check (which a user here sorted out for me) that brings up an error if the user tries to enter more than 100 in each box.

I need a method that looks at the number entered in the textfield and then looks at the total of the 3 and then adjusts the others accordingly.

An example would be say i typed the following:

Example 1
A = 50
I would expect B to fill in with the remaining 50

Example 2
A =40 B=50 C=10

I then change A to 60. The total is now 120.
I would like it to look at B, then take 20 away so I have the following.
A=60 B=30 C=10

I've seen scenarios where a user has 2 textfields that he wants to total 100 but I have not seen threads that ask for 3.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any programming before? The step from adding 'the other text box' to 'the other two text boxes' is a tiny step. Do you have the code working for just two boxes?

Comment: I've got experience with VBA and have been trying to learn objective C using books and online tutorials.

The actual addition part is simple enough, it's just that there would be some mathematical checks. What if B was 10 and C was 50 in my second example? I wouldn't be able to take away 20 from B as I would get -10. 

I just thought i'd post as someone might have been through the same situation.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It isn't clear. As I understand it, you want to satisfy "all boxes should add up to 100". If this is the case, in example 1 surely it should place 25 in box B and 25 in box X? Also, in example 2 surely it should adjust both fields B and C, not just field B? Why is B more special than C?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I wasn't sure how to approach the changing of the other boxes. In my example above, I just change the figure in the next box (A ->B, B->C etc).

If I want to ammend both the other text boxes, it would probably be better but then I get into issues with rounding. What if I enter 85 in A. The remaining fugure to be allocated across B and C is 15. 15/2 = 7.5. If I round up both figures, my total is 101. I'm just not really sure what the best way to approach this is.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It may do what you want.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, it's just the problem with rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have three fields. This is pseudocode. Attach this delegate function to all 3 text areas.

```
// Take 3 fields
FieldA, FieldB, FieldC

// Total target to reach
TotalTarget = 100

// The total we currently have
total = FieldA + FieldB + FieldC

// Work out how much we are under by. 
// If positive, we are under. If negative, we are over.
underBy = TotalTarget - total

// Now two variables for the 'other two' fields.
if sender == FieldA:
  other1 = FieldB, other2 = FieldC
if sender == FieldB:
  other1 = FieldA, other2 = FieldC
if sender == FieldC:
  other1 = FieldA, other2 = FieldB

// Split the difference and assign to other 2 fields so they are raised or lowered the same amount.
// If under, add, if over, subtract.
other1 = other1 + overBy / 2
other2 = other2 + overBy / 2        

// This will add 1 or 0 to other2 (i.e. compensate for round-down)
other2 = other2 + overBy % 2;
```

If you use integer division, then you will have a rounding problem. Hint: if it's odd, you can add one to one of the fields.

Make sure you write tests. I've not tried any of this, but it should work.

Comment: Really sorry mate, I didn't mention that I only want the boxes to take whole numbers. I've written about the problems that may cause above in the reply to my question. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: This is fine, hence my comment about integer division.

Comment: By default, with integer division, i'm guessing it rounds up? 25/2 = 12.5 but it'll return 13.

So i could use an if function, if underBy is even, do as you wrote, if it's odd, other2 + overbuy/2 -1.

That sound good?

Comment: No, it rounds down. Always.

Comment: Heh, I'm on SO for more than one reason!

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot for the help. Sorry I wasn't too clear in the question. I really appreciate you taking the time to reply, this really did help me.

Comment: That's ok! But you should read up on integer division. VBA really is a million miles from Obj-C!